# I want to rename the index of my array using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi I'm having my personal experiment with arrays what I was trying to do is to rename the index of the array from the result of my text field that dynamically adds using Javascript(I dont want to use jquery or other libraries like angular js). See image below for the UI 
[image: imgUI]

the problem is that the output looks like this

[image: imgArry]

**I want to be able to rename the index of the array generated**(THIS IS WHAT I WANT FYI)
btw PHP handles my data and Javascript obviously handles my textfield manipulation
see my code

**Javascript**

```
var countBox =1;
var boxName = 0;
var boxName2 = 0;
function addInput()
{
    var boxName="index"+countBox;
    var boxName2="value"+countBox; 
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="aindex" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><input type="text" name="avalue[]" id="'+boxName2+'" value="'+boxName2+'" "  /><br/>';
    countBox += 1;
}
```

**PHP**

```
   if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $b = $_POST['avalue'];

$results = print_r( $b, true); 

 file_put_contents( $filepath, print_r($b, true));
}
```

Comment: `'....<input type="text" name="avalue['+boxName+']"  />....'`

Comment: @Dr.Molle Hi if I do that it will only name index1, index2 etc what I want is to get the value of the aindex field as my index name for the text field

Comment: some people are worth slapping why would someone vote to close my question without explaining? just because you can't or don't know the answer for my question is that it? what a troll

Comment: What is unclear is what you mean when you say you want to rename the index of an array and where you'd like to do so. In JavaScript, arrays are indexed by numeric values starting at zero. If you wish to use some other value as an index, you'll need to use a hash (object with key=>value). Could you clarify?

Comment: Well, some people ask question which are not clear to ot other peoples. My suggestion whould result in an array `["indexN"=>"valueN"]` ... when you want to achieve something different(before you've edited your question)...for me it's simply not clear what you are asking for. Don't care for close-votes,take care of clear questions.

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML, it appears you want to have pairs of form fields to hold keys and values? If so, just set the name of your all of your key fields to "keys[]" and all the value fields to "values[]" which when submitted will provide two arrays to your backend service.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean.. can you elaborate it for me further please? thanks.. and yes you are most definitely correct when you said that I want to have a pair of form fields that holds the key and values for the array that I will be generating